# Listview item color

Tags: android

My list view is a multiple selection list view. i have to show the selected list view items in one color(say green) and the other items in some other color(red). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by showing "items in [...] color." The easiest way to change items' colors is to do it in the Adapter's getView() or bindView() method.

Answer (score 0):

In the onItemSelectListner change the item background to whichever you need.

Comment: THe problem with this (and Rowno's similar comment) is that you need to keep track of this state for example when you rotate the screen. Better to store it as a property in the underlying data set and render the list item appropriately, as Romain Guy mentions.

Comment: As far as I understand, you want the user to select multiple items and change its color. And I think doing this in the getView() and bindView() won't fully solve your problem. These methods are called when the view gets added to the view.

Comment: @Karan is there any example for onItemSelectListener...?

Answer (score 0):

You could call the [setBackgroundColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29) method in the select event to change the background color.